# Updates to chrome extension popup disappear

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

So I'm trying to make an extension that takes the contents put in the search bar in popup.html and adds it as a div with a checkbox and button similar to the one that already exists. The issue is that every time I use the search the div will add properly then immediately disappear. For example if I were to type hello into the search bar and hit submit on popup.html the hello div will create and show up for a single frame then disappear and the popup.html is reset to where it was before anything was searched for. How can I make it so that the content stays on the popup and doesn't just reset to the original immediately after?

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "test 2.0",
  "version": "2.0",
  "description": "test extension",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "images/16.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "author": "Cormac",
  "commands": {},
  "incognito": "split",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "declarativeContent",
    "storage",
    "tabs"
  ],
  "short_name": "test"
}
```

**popup.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- popup when icon is clicked for extension-->
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="search-container">
      <form>
        <input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search">
        <button id="searchbut" class="submit" type="submit"></button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div id="movies">
      <div id="mov">
        <p id = "p">Movie 1</p>
        <label class="switch">
          <input type="checkbox" checked>
          <span class="slider round"></span>
        </label>
        <button type="submit"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src="popup.js"></script>
</html>
```

If someone were to search for "Movie 2", then movie 2 should be put in a duplicate of the mov div and placed after the first mov div. Thus there would be a mov div with Movie 1 and a mov div with Movie 2.

**popup.js**

```
'use strict';

let page = document.getElementById('movies');

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  var button = document.getElementById('searchbut');
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
        addMovie();
    });
});

function addMovie(){
    var x = document.getElementById("search");
    var movies = document.getElementById("movies");
    movies.innerHTML += "<p id = \"p\">" + x.value + "</p><label class=\"switch\"><input type=\"checkbox\" checked><span class=\"slider round\"></span></label><button type=\"submit\"></button></div>";
}
```

Additionally in trying to find a solution for this phantom content update I've seen that a common issue is that once the popup is closed it will also reset. This is another issue I expect to encounter after this current one is resolved. If someone could explain that as well that would be amazing.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the form tags:

```
<div class="search-container">
    <input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search">
    <button id="searchbut" class="submit" type="submit"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: having spent a few hours on this the simplicity of this solution makes me a lil depressed